# Retrieve From Access from two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying for retrieve some information from two tables in Access.
The method is working but with an anomaly.

Even if a column is null or empty it affected by the one that is not empty,
and when I use the `where`syntax it shows only the matches.
I need to retrieve all of it.
This is a line of SQL I am using whiteout WHERE

```
SELECT Article.Code, Article.Libelle,Fabricant.Libelle FROM [Article],[Fabricant]
```

Comment: It will be dificult to help without the tables definitions and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it sounds like you're looking for an `OUTER JOIN` :

```
SELECT A.Code, A.libelle, F.Libelle
FROM Article A
    LEFT JOIN Fabricant F ON A.Libelle = F.Libelle
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Hi friend , I take you code and doing dome modifications and it's work thanks you are my saver .

SELECT A.Code, A.libelle, F.Libelle FROM Article A LEFT JOIN Fabricant F ON A.Fabricant = F.Code